# How can I stop a JS function from running on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following code running and I need to make it stop if you are using a mobile device

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var inHeight = $("#wrapper").innerHeight();
    $("#wrapper .col").each(function(){
        $(this).height(inHeight+"px");
        $(this).find('.content').height((inHeight-60)+"px");
    });
});
```

Can I use something like `if($(window).width()<600){ /* do something */ }` If so what shall I write between the curved brackets?

Thank you!

Comment: Your solution looks like it will work - have you even tried it?

Comment: Just invert it (`.width() > 600`) and place your code within.

Comment: You're on the right track but instead of preventing below 600 why not just execute above 600?

Comment: NO NO NO. Do not use the window width to determine if it is a mobile device!

Comment: The is a question that might help you [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Comment: It's going to be particularly difficult to implement this using window width due to the fact that a non-mobile browser can be resized down to those widths too. When that happens, you would have to undo what the script did, then redo it when it's resized back out, etc. Just check the useragent. Or better yet, don't design around equal-height columns unless you're giving them a static height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
if(!(/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android|webOS|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var inHeight = $("#wrapper").innerHeight();
    $("#wrapper .col").each(function(){
        $(this).height(inHeight+"px");
        $(this).find('.content').height((inHeight-60)+"px");
    });
}); 

}
```

So if it is **not** a mobile device then you run the code

Using `$(window).width` it is not a very good solution. Think what will happen if i am not using a mobile device and just change dimensions in my browser window

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };



if( isMobile.any() ) {....} else { // place your code here }
```